# $\alpha, \beta$ are roots of $x^2+px+q=0, f(x)=(\alpha+\beta)x-\left(\frac{\alpha^2+\beta^2}2\right)x^2+\left(\frac{\alpha^3+\beta^3}3\right)x^3-...$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, roots

> If $\ln(1+x)=x-\dfrac {x^2}2+\dfrac {x^3}3-\dfrac{x^4}4+...$ and $\alpha$ & $\beta$ are roots of the equation $x^2+px+q=0$. If $f(x)=(\alpha+\beta)x-\left(\dfrac{\alpha^2+\beta^2}2\right)x^2+\left(\dfrac{\alpha^3+\beta^3}3\right)x^3-\left(\dfrac{\alpha^4+\beta^4}4\right)x^4+...$ then find $f'(x)$ in terms of $p,q$

By Vieta's formula

$\alpha+\beta=-p,\; \alpha\beta=q$

$\ln(1+(\alpha+\beta)x)=(\alpha+\beta)x-\dfrac {(\alpha+\beta)^2}2x^2+\dfrac {(\alpha+\beta)^3}3x^3-\dfrac{(\alpha+\beta)^4}4x^4+...$

$f'(x)=(\alpha+\beta)-(\alpha^2+\beta^2)x+(\alpha^3+\beta^3)x^2-(\alpha^4+\beta^4)x^3$

$\alpha^2+\beta^2=(\alpha+\beta)^2-2\alpha\beta=p^2-2q$

$\alpha^3+\beta^3=(\alpha+\beta)^3-3\alpha\beta(\alpha+\beta)=-p^3+3pq$

Not able to work around and conclude.

Comment: The first part "if $\ln(1+x)=...$ should be written as a hint...

Comment: @JeanMarie I think that's to calculate $f(1+(\alpha+\beta)x)$. I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=(\alpha+\beta)x-\left(\dfrac{\alpha^2+\beta^2}2\right)x^2+\left(\dfrac{\alpha^3+\beta^3}3\right)x^3-\left(\dfrac{\alpha^4+\beta^4}4\right)x^4+...$

$f(x)=\ln(1+\alpha x)+\ln(1+\beta x)$

$f(x)=\ln(1+(\alpha+\beta)x+\alpha\beta x^2)$

$f(x)=\ln(1-px+qx^2)$

Can you continue??